# Ubuntu upgrade: not enough disk space in /var/

Tags: partitioning, upgrade

I'm currently running Ubuntu 15.10 but trying to upgrade to 16.04.
When I run `sudo do-release-upgrade`, the process aborts with the message:

```
Not enough free disk space 

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 2,206 M free 
space on disk '/var'. Please free at least an additional 4,623 k of 
disk space on '/var'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages 
of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get clean` but it does not reduce the space significantly, besides, I don't quite see why this error would happen.
My disk partitions look like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           787M  9.8M  777M   2% /run
/dev/sda6        26G   14G   11G  58% /
tmpfs           3.9G  233M  3.7G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4       923M  8.6M  851M   1% /tmp
/dev/sda3       3.7G  1.4G  2.1G  40% /var
/dev/sda2        78G   47G   28G  63% /home
/dev/sda1       256M   32M  225M  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs           787M   12K  787M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           787M   20K  787M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Why does the upgrader need space on the /var partition if that is not where the OS is installed?

Also, just in case it helps, this is the inside of /var (which looks pretty normal to me):

```
total 88
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root      4096 Aug 17  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root      4096 Feb  4 19:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      4096 Jan 26 19:38 backups
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root      4096 Oct 23 22:24 cache
drwxrwsrwt   2 root whoopsie  4096 Feb  3 22:25 crash
drwxr-xr-x  79 root root      4096 Feb  4 19:38 lib
drwxrwsr-x   2 root staff     4096 Apr 17  2015 local
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         9 Aug 16  2015 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x  13 root syslog    4096 Feb  4 18:45 log
drwx------   2 root root     16384 Aug 16  2015 lost+found
drwxrwsr-x   2 root mail      4096 Apr 22  2015 mail
drwxrwsrwt   2 root whoopsie  4096 Apr 22  2015 metrics
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      4096 Apr 22  2015 opt
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         4 Aug 16  2015 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root      4096 Feb 26  2016 spool
drwxrwxrwt 126 root root     20480 Feb  4 20:11 tmp
drwxrwxr-x   2 root plugdev   4096 Sep  3  2013 upek_data
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Tip: 'Disk Usage Analyzer' is great for finding the unwanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the upgrader need space on the /var partition if that is not where the OS is installed?

The updater needs to download all the replacement .deb packages of the newer version before it can install them. It stores these files in /var/cache/apt/archives.

From the info you provided, you have a separate /var partition with only about 2 GB of space left. Your current root partition uses about 14 GB. Even allowing for extraneous packages that need not be replicated in the newer version (e.g. old kernels, etc), the difference between the two is simply too great, about 4.6 GB according to the updater.

This problem would not have happened if you did not elect to have a separate /var partition, and just kept /var inside the root partition, seeing that you have a rather sizable / partition.

One way to solve the problem is to resize (enlarge) the /var partition by taking space from either /dev/sda6 or /dev/sda2. You will have to do this from a live medium (not from your current hard drive installation) since you cannot modify a partition while it is mounted. I personally prefer using the gparted tool from a live ubuntu USB stick.

---

Note: If you haven't done so already, now would be a good time to back up your system. Once the required files are downloaded and the update starts, there is no going back to the previous version unless you reinstall or have a back-up to restore.

Comment: Thanks! I remember when I partitioned my disk I had some (presumably convincing) reason for having a separate /var partition but I cannot remember it for the life of me.  I probably have some live USBs hanging around so I'll follow your advice for resizing /var, though I may just decide to merge it into /.